# Как создать asp.net mvc проект 4той версии с .net 4.0 на visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Я создаю пустой проект, можно ли как то подключить в него MVC, и назначить ему 4-ую версию. Ибо по стандарту ставится 5-ая.
Влияет ли как то версия Visual studio на версию MVC?

Comment: Запустить Visual Studio Installer, выбрать пункт ASP.NET and web development, поставить галку ASP.NET MVC 4, нажать Modify. Думаю, после этого появится проект нужного типа.

Comment: Вы бы всё-таки создавали проект хотя бы на 5той версии, а не на устаревшей платформе. Да, формально его [до 1 июля 2019 года поддерживают](https://www.asp.net/support), но в общем-то уже как-то пора посвежее технологии брать.

Comment: @A K , Да я бы вот сам рад, но такое ТЗ, строго  MVC 4

Comment: Сочувствую. А пробовали совет @AlexanderPetrov , подошло?

Answer (score 1):

MVC 5 вышла в 2013 году, так что неудивительно, что поддержка MVC 4 в VS 2017 по факту отсутствует.

Как указали в комментариях, можно поставить опциональный компонент MVC 4, чтобы открывать старые проекты, но проблема в том, что шаблоны для создания новых элементов все равно будут отсутствовать.

Так что если нужна полноценная поддержка, ставьте старую студию, в идеале 2012.

Comment: Благодарю, так и сделаю пожалуй

Comment: @Soulrise43 Если ответ вам помог, вы можете его принять